# Comparison between Distributed Online LDA implemented by PySpark and Gensim

Tags: pyspark, nlp, apache-spark-mllib, gensim, topic-modeling

Distributed Online LDA is implemented by [Spark MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda) and [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/dist_lda.html). I would like to choose one of them to do my project.

At present, I already have a hadoop system running with 7 worker nodes.

Could someone having experience with both give a recommendation and point out pros and cons of them, e.g. the difficulty of cluster setup, speed of the modelling process, etc. Thanks.